# Unexpected buffer result when fetching PNG image

Tags: node.js, request

I am fetching several random PNG images from the web using popular libraries such as [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and [request](https://github.com/request/request) but both seem to be returning the wrong file signature.

Please take the following snippet as an example (https://repl.it/@phobos/Request-png-file-wrong-buffer):

```
const request = require('request');
const png = require('pngjs').PNG;

const url = 'https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-100kb.png';

  function getPngBuffer() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(url, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err || !body) return reject(err || new Error('no body'));

      const buf = Buffer.from(body);

      console.log('\nGOT SIG: ', buf.slice(0, 8));
      console.log('EXPECTED SIG:', '<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a>\n')

      new png({ filterType:4 }).parse(buf, (err, png) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve('Worked!')
      });

    });
  })
}

getPngBuffer()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

When I request an arbitrary PNG image and look at the very first characters via the Buffer API, I see the wrong values.

According to the png spec, it should be `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a`, indeed, if I download the image via my browser and inspect it via a hex editor it is indeed this.

When I log `buf` it instead gives me `ef bf bd 50 4e 47 0d 0a`.

Essentially, instead of `âPNG` it returns `o?=PNG` which breaks things like `pngjs`.

What's the best way to resolve this apparent issue, I really don't want to mutate `buf` to give it the expected file signature as I'd also have to mutate the CRC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am having this exact problem in python - 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a -> ef bf bd 50 4e 47 0d 0a - I am so grateful to find from your question that it's the encoding rather than something else! Now to fix it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the encoding, without setting one, the default will be `utf8` and the `body` will be converted to a string.

Just pass `encoding: null` to request, and then drop `Buffer.from` since `body` will be already a buffer.

> encoding - encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If
>   null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the
>   default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter
>   to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). **(Note: if**
>   **you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)**

```
const options =  {
  url: url,
  encoding: null
};

request.get(options, (err, res, buf) => {
  if (err || !buf) return reject(err || new Error('no body'));

  console.log('\nGOT SIG: ', buf.slice(0, 8));
  console.log('EXPECTED SIG:', '<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a>\n')

  new png({ filterType:4 }).parse(buf, (err, png) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve('Worked!')
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a relatively straightforward fix I think, we need to set the request encoding to null:

```
const request = require('request');
const png = require('pngjs').PNG;

const url = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5f/3a/bb/5f3abbf32683629689eda72189f755da.png';

  function getPngBuffer() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var options = 
    {
      url: url,
      encoding: null
    };
    request.get(options, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err || !body) return reject(err || new Error('no body'));

      const buf = Buffer.from(body);

      console.log('\nGOT SIG: ', buf.slice(0, 8));
      console.log('EXPECTED SIG:', '<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a>\n')

      new png({ filterType:4 }).parse(buf, (err, png) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve('Worked!')
      });

    });
  })
}

getPngBuffer()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Just set the encoding to null in the options object passed to request.get. I've encountered this a few times with images.

From the Request docs:

encoding - encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)

This solution is working for me (although I'm using a different image, I'd expect the result to be the same)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation snippet!